# Jetty vs Tomcat with Oracle XE

Tags: java, windows, oracle, tomcat, jetty

Setup: Server Application needs to run on Tomcat / Jetty. Oracle 11g XE is the db behind. OS:Windows 8.

I'm sure, the application is making huge number of jdbc connections to the db.

This is running perfect on Tomcat but not on Jetty. Its throwing following ORA Exception and the war is not deployed.

*OracleException: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack*

I could able to fix this by increasing no of sessions, processes and reducing pmon time on DB in case of Jetty.

1. My Question is why only Jetty needs so many extra db resources when tomcat could able to handle it? Isn't it against the belief that jetty needs lesser resources than tomcat?
2. What is the best way to evaluate Tomcat or Jetty when I've very limited hardware resources like 4GB RAM (for Windows8+Tomcat+Application (2GB) + Oracle XE (1GB).
3. What can be the most effective individual memory allocation in such scenario.

Comment: here's discussion about the error https://community.oracle.com/thread/362226 
...and they suggested to increase the value for PROCESSES parameter

Comment: The thing that is needing extra resources is your Oracle XE drivers, not Jetty.  Have you considered solutions that reuse and/or pool various Oracle resources? (connections? caching? etc...)

Comment: Yes, I could able to solve based on this link. My question is why do I need to increase when I have to use jetty where as tomcat could able to run it without increasing no of sessions and processes?